# MATLAB read from subset of netcdf files

Tags: matlab, netcdf

I have large netcdf files of hourly wind speed (684 (west-to-east) by 447 (south-to-north) data points by 72 (hours).  So, the array is 684x447x72 for a single file and I'm reading 122 per year.  I concatenate the 72hrs and # of files per year.  So, in the end I have a 684x447x(72x122) array for each year.  I need to read exactly half the data points in the file (western plot) and plot the data and then read the other half of the data points (eastern plot) and plot the data.  I'm not understanding how to manage reading these data points.

Here is what i've tried in my read loop: "var80speed" is 684x447x72.  "nametest" is my .nc path and file.  [1 1 1] is the vector for the starting location?  Is that bottom left or upper right in the starting read location of the .nc file? If 684 is west-to-east as it states in the .nc header information in each file, then it seems I should read exactly half of the data points and all of the north-to-south points for the first plot and then would this change to 684/2 for the start and 684 for the end to do the second plot?  Any help here is much appreciated!

```
var80speed = single(cat(3,var80speed, ncread(nametest,myVarName,[1 1 1], [ 684/2 447 72 ])));
```

%Loop in code to read .nc files:

```
for kk = 1:numyrs
    for ii = 1:(numrowsfilestoread(1,kk))
        infiletest = strcat(files2test(filestoread(ii,kk),:),'.nc');
        nametest = fullfile(pathname,infiletest);
        disp(infiletest);
        ncidt = netcdf.open(nametest);
        var80speed = single(cat(3,var80speed, ncread(nametest,myVarName,[1 1 1], [684/2 447 72])));
        %obtain mean of filelength period considered
        netcdf.close(ncidt);
        fname = strcat(num2str(years(kk)),'_80wspeed_spd');
        path = 'J:\\MATLAB\READ_netcdf_TTnc files\outfiles_text\';
        pathfile = strcat(path,fname);
        if ii == 61 % save middle of year
            savefast(pathfile,'var80speed');
            var80speed = []; 
        end
    end
    load(pathfile,'var80speed');
    var80speed2 = var80speed;
    var80speedall = cat(3,var80speed,var80speed2);
    clear var80speed;
    clear var80speed2;
    var80speed = []; var80speed2 = [];
    savefast(pathfile,'var80speedall');
 end
```

Comment: Can you add some more information to your question.  Does the code you have work?  Are you getting errors?  Are there sample files somewhere?   Can you add more surrounding code for your loop (initialization of `var80speed`, etc.?

Comment: I'm getting no errors and I'm not sure I'm reading the .nc file correctly.  Here is the read loop:

Comment: Ok, I think I answered the questions regarding ncread and its `start` and `count` arguments.  There is certain room to improve your code above beyond that but I don't know if that is what you are really looking for.  Ex.  you call `netcdf.open` and `close` but don't do anything with that... either by mistake or you cut some stuff out of your example.   You are also doing a bunch of appending to `var80speed` that would be faster with some pre-allocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give you a partial answer to some of your questions until some more information is given.  I'll focus on this part using the [Matlab multidimention syntax](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html).:

```
ncread(nametest,myVarName,[1 1 1], [ 684/2 447 72 ])
```

This will start at index (1,1,1) and read 342 rows, 447 columns, 72 pages (hour). If your assumptions about dimensions are correct then this should read the "western" data for all of the times in the file.

To get the "Eastern" you would do this:

```
ncread(nametest,myVarName,[684/2+1 1 1], [ 684/2 447 72 ])
```

This will start at the 343rd row (beginning of east), 1st column, 1st page (hour) and read the same number of rows, columns, & pages as before.

Note: From [ncread docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ncread.html) the last argument is the `count`

> Vector of length N specifying the number of elements to read along the
>   corresponding dimensions. If a particular element of count is Inf,
>   ncread reads data until the end of the corresponding dimension.

So this does not change between West and East calls to ncread since you are reading the same amount of data each time.  However, you could use `Inf` in place of the numbers.

Comment: ncread(nametest,myVarName,[684/2+1 1 1], [ 684/2 447 72 ])  In this line of code, I think you mean in the second argument:  [ 684 447 72 ]?

Comment: also, where is starting point [1 1 1]?  Is that bottom left or upper left?  Thank you!

Comment: No the last argument `count` is the amount of elements to read.  As I said in the answer above this is unchanged regardless of reading East or West data. In both cases you want to read 342x447x72 elements.

Comment: Ok, I'm confused about reading "columns" ,which I think of in terms of like longitude and "rows" as similar to latitude.  Using ncdisp(path,myVarName) shows west_east = 684 and south_north = 447.  To me, that represents roughly a rectangle of points west to east or along the x axis == 684 and the points along the y axis or south_north == 447.  Is that correct?  Displaying my data in a plot, which is the entire USA, is indeed a rectangle with a longer west_east dimension compared to south_north dimension.

Comment: It all depends on the documentation of your data ... which I don't have.    Assuming dim1 (West to East = 1 to 684), dim2 (South to North = 1 to 447) & dim3 (Hours 1 to 72).  Then [1 1 1]  ([lon lat time]) is South West Corner of your map at time 1.   [343 1 1] is center south point on your map at time 1.

Comment: i'm seeing it now I think.  Then, according to my data doc or using ncdisp on my data, then data reading from west_east would be 1:684/2 and reading all the south_north points would be 1:447 starting in the SW corner according to my data documentation.  Thank you,